# Manually moving an app back to internal storage

Tags: internal-storage, sd-card, installation, android-11

I am using Android 11 on a Fairphone 3. I have added a microSD card that I use as storage for apps, and have some apps installed on the SD card. But some of those apps does not work properly, these apps are reset every time I launch them (connection profile and parameters), just like if I newly installed them.

I recently installed a new app (TooGoodToGo) : which automatically installed on the SD card by default, and it always crashes at startup. I think the crash might be due to the fact it is installed on the SD card. But when I want to move it to internal storage, I have a "Insufficient space" error, despite the fact that it only weights 50MB and I have 20GB available on the internal storage ...

What is (are) the issue(s) here ? Why can't I move back the app ? Or how to install this app directly to the internal storage ? And why are some app installed on the SD card not saving anything ?

Thanks in advance for any leads you could give me on this :)

Comment: How exactly are you installing apps on SD Card?

Comment: I don't know exactly : when installing a new app from the Google Play Store, it is automatically installed on the SD card, and I don't know how to change this behaviour. A while ago I also moved some already installed apps manually, using the "move" button in the app settings.

Comment: Did you try installing after removing SD card?  It should get installed to internal storage

Comment: Well, it worked ! So the issue was indeed related to app being installed on the SD card. But I still don't understand why it doesn't work on SD card, why can't I move the app back to internal storage, and why can't I choose the default location of new apps ?